# Is the set of all invertible $n \times n$ matrices a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing, matrix-calculus

I'm studying Algebra and I'm asked to prove or disprove "Is the set of all invertible $n \times n$ matrices a vector space?" I assume with respect to the usual matrix-sum and scalar multiplication.  I found that is true, but I'm not sure how to prove it.

My problem here is that this statement is too "broad", i.e. I cannot create a matrix with arbitrary values a,b,c,d,(...) considering that I don't know the size of the matrix.

My idea was to prove in a first time that the set of all invertible 2 x 2 matrices of real number is a vector space and then to show that this property could be extended to bigger matrices. However I don't know how to do it and it's precisely here that I need a little help ; how can I show that we can extend our statement?

Is it enough to say that the matrix's size doesn't affect in any way properties we need to check? 
Is my overall strategy wrong?
Any form of help would be very appreciated on this dubious answer.

Comment: Is the zero matrix invertible?

Comment: How about trying with the set of $1 \times 1$ matrices, that is, the real numbers. Do the non-zero real numbers form a vector space?

Comment: ... No, so there is no neutral element for addition. Was it as simple as that ?

Answer (score 16):

The set of all invertible $n\times n$ matrices of real numbers is NOT a vector space.

Let for example $I$, the unit matrix is invertible and so is $-I$. But their sum $I+(-I)=0$ is definitely not invertible!

Comment: My bad. Thanks for your help

Comment: What if you use a different addition operator?

Comment: Which addition operator?

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis multiplication for example.

Answer (score -2):

The set of all invertible $n \times n$ matrices is not a vector space with respect to the typical matrix addition and scalar multiplication operations and the typical matrix zero.

However,

The special orthogonal group (rotation matrices) is a vector space if you use matrix multiplication for the addition operator and the identity matrix as the zero matrix.

You also have to make scalar multiplication exponentials.

$ s \otimes A = A^s$

You can also change the zero matrix to be a matrix $C$ with:

$A\oplus B = A B C^{-1}$

and

$ s \otimes A = A^s C^{-s}$.

Then,

$ A \oplus C = A$.

And invertible $n \times n$ matrices are just rotation matrices with a scaling part and so are also vector spaces.

Comment: It is certainly possible to endow the set with some structure so that it becomes a real vector spaces, but this works for any set of the right cardinality so it is really besides the point. The question ought to mean the usual operations. So really if it is a subspace of the space of all matrices.

Comment: If you really so strongly feel that the question "ought" to mean the usual operations then go and edit the question to say so.

Comment: Your wish is my command.

Comment: There are many things wrong with this. The operations written are not well defined. A vector space over reals is topologically $\mathbb{R}^n$ (with topology induced by the vector space structure), and so the invertible matrices with usual topology can not be endowed with any vector space structure (of course any set with cardinality of continuum can be made into vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, by transferring the operations from a bijection with any vector space; but that is of little interest).